# How to fix extremely slow Microsoft Store downloads?

Tags: windows-11, download, windows-store

I recently helped set up a new computer with Windows 11 (preinstalled), and while it went rather smoothly, there's a problem that the Microsoft Store is downloading and installing *extremely* slowly: It takes forever for any download or update to start. The download itself is painfully slow (as in sub-kb/s-slow, or no progress at all), and even after the download is completed, the actual installation/update also takes very long. There is no indication of what the program is doing all that time, and no significant CPU or network activity, neither from the app itself nor from other apps. For all other matters, the download speed of the computer is fine.

This seems to be a common problem, even mentioned several times in the app's own reviews in the Microsoft Store itself. But while there are countless guides on the net, I could not find any solution that works in my case, and no related question here. I tried, among others, all the steps [here](https://appuals.com/fix-microsoft-store-slow-download/), but none of those made a difference. Those include, e.g., using the Windows Troubleshooter, "Repairing" or "Resetting" the App, deactivating download limiters or Antivirus (temporarily), and clearing different Cache directories. The situation was the same each time I tried over the course of several weeks, so I'd also rule out a temporary server problem.

So my question is: Is there anything else I can try besides the steps mentioned in the above article and elsewhere? Or should those definitely work and I must have been doing something wrong? If there is no fix, is there another way to update the builtin Microsoft utility apps? (Some just refuse to start before updates are installed.)

---

Additional information:

- Task Manager shows zero downstream for Microsoft Store even while it's (allegedly) updating something, although there *is* some progress when I check back several minutes or hours later, but not much (a few kB)
- for other apps, downstream is fine (downloading large files, network-installers, etc., all around 20 mbps)
- there are very few other programs installed since setup (basically just Office, a taxes program, Avira antivirus), and the problem with Microsoft Store was from the very beginning, before installing *anything* else

---

**Update:** In the end, I did not do the Repair Install [suggested in comments](https://superuser.com/questions/1783935/how-to-fix-extremely-slow-microsoft-store-downloads#comment2787390_1783937). It's not my PC and I only irregularly have access to it and did not want to risk leaving it in a non-operational state.

However, after the problem persisted for several weeks, when I checked back on the PC now the Store worked fine, downloading and installing all updates quickly without any fuss. I'll check back again later, but seems like the problem somehow just resolved itself.

Comment: The Microsoft Store is just a slow software with bad backend servers. It's all Microsoft fault for being a bad service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows 11 Tools, Resource Monitor, to examine Network Activity, and determine if Store is the only slow network process or whether Store is causing all network to slow down.

It may be the download is conflicting with something you have installed. You might see if Store works on a different machine.

[image: Network Activity]

Comment: As I said, other downloads work fine. ~20mbps downstream in Firefox with and without store running in parallel, and zero downstream in store with and without other downloads in parallel. I don't have another Windows PC available for testing at the moment. The problem was there right from the start, without any other software being installed.

Comment: Microsoft Store is not an issue on any of my machines. Maybe try a Windows 11 Repair Install and Keep Everything.  (non invasive).  I assume you are using a valid Microsoft Account.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Windows 11 Repair Install"? Re-Installing the Store app, or the entire system? The latter seems a bit extreme. I already tried "repairing" or "resetting" the Store app from the Troubleshooting section. Yes, I am using a legit (preinstalled on new PC) and activated Windows 11 and have a Microsoft account.

Comment: A Windows 11 Repair Install is in no way extreme. It will fix your system, Keep Everything, and put it all back.    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11   .   Select download (not upgrade) , download to a USB and run setup from the USB.    Apps like the Store and all will be reinstalled.

Comment: Also make sure you did not make any changes with the registry editor which may have upset something.

Comment: I didn't. Thanks for the tips, I may try the repair-install as a last resort, but for now I'd first wait and hope for another solution.

Comment: If you reinstalled the Store and that did not work, then a Repair Install is likely then only method left in this case.

Comment: This is a bug of the store. In the code.

Answer (score -1):

I faced this very problem, and read all the articles on the net - but one is hard to find. The problem for me was the Microsoft Gaming services - so if you have gamings switched on this is a very likely cause

`Settings` => `Gaming` => `Game Mode` - switch this setting off
In Powershell with admin rights remove the gaming service

```
get-appxpackage Microsoft.GamingServices | remove-AppxPackage -allusers
```

In `Settings` => `Apps` remove the Xbox App

Reboot, run the Microsoft Store, and your store runs faster, and will complete.

From the event log the gaming service tries to update and fails to install. This then tries to install again and just loops, etc.