# Windows Store downloads are severerely rate limited - why?

Tags: windows, windows-11, download, bandwidth, windows-store

Windows Store downloads are severely rate limited on my Windows 11 (10.0.22631.3085 23H2) computer and I can't figure out why (nor can our IT guys). What could be causing it?

The download rate is typically around ~1 Kb/s a second. This makes it look like it's stuck, but it's not - it's just very, very slow. That said, it will often sit there not downloading at all, intermittently downloading very slowly.

[image]

I have tried all the troubleshooting advice I can find.

My internet speed is fine. Non-Store downloads are fine. Downloads of packages found using https://store.rg-adguard.net/ work fine, suggesting the limit is being imposed by the Store on my computer rather than an external limit.

Things I have tried:

- Connected to a variety of different networks with and without VPNs at different locations globally;
- Ran `wsreset.exe`;
- Ran `Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` This reinstalls and re-registers all built-in Store apps on the system;
- In Settings > System > System Components > Microsoft Store > Advanced options I have done a Repair and Reset;
- Windows "[Game Mode](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/help/games-apps/game-setup-and-play/use-game-mode-gaming-on-pc)" is turned off and I removed Microsoft.GamingServices ([as suggested here](https://superuser.com/a/1803813/2924));
- Set Windows Update > Advanced Options > Delivery Optimisation > Advanced Options > Percentage of measured bandwidth (measured against the update source) to 100% bandwidth for both foreground and background;
- Delivery Optimisation > Allow downloads from other PCs is disabled;

The only thing that I have not tried is disabling Bitdefender Endpoint Security. Could Bitdefender really be the problem here?

The computer is attached to a Windows domain and my user account is limited, although I have a local admin account I can elevate to perform tasks I need local admin priviledges for (e.g. installing software).

I'm stumped. What else could I try to troubleshoot or diagnose this issue?

Comment: Open an admin command prompt and run wsreset.  Restart and check.  I am not sure if that is the same as the App reset

Comment: Does the download eventually come through, and when it does it finally comes through at an expected rate?  It almost sounds like a firewall or proxy with anti-virus is buffering the download until it can get the full file to scan.  When this happens the fw/proxy releases a few bytes at a time to the client to keep the connection open and then does a full send after it has been able to scan the file.  Sporadic-ness could be the sites the fw/proxy is configured to scan or not scan.  If this is the case, this is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: Check if you have any limitations in *Settings > Windows Update > Advanced Options > Delivery Optimization > Advanced Options*.

Comment: "The computer is attached to a Windows domain..." Do others on that domain have a similar issue?

Comment: @John I've tried that - see second bullet in my list.

Comment: @squillman No, starts at around 100b/s and remains at about that rate until it eventually finishes. Although this sounds like a good enough reason to at least try with Bitdefender disabled.

Comment: @harrymc See the last two bullets in my list; no other limitations as far as I can see

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, not that we know of.

Comment: Yes, do try with Bitdefender disabled and every other security software and firewall.